# Pechkin dll (htmltopdf conversion) style issue with https protocol

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf, pechkin

I am Using Pechkin dll in c# to convert HTML file to PDF file. converted PDF file has Style issue only when application runs with HTTPs protocol but it works well in HTTP protocol. could anyone help me?

Comment: visit here https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2120

Comment: i am using Pechkin dll in c#.net which is a .NET Wrapper for WkHtmlToPdf DLL, a library that uses the Web Kit engine to convert HTML pages to PDF

Answer (score -2):

Please check your style sheet's link and use the Protocol-relative URL. 
This is a very useful suggestion, please view the link: [Problems loading style sheets over https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452519/problems-loading-style-sheets-over-https)