# // does not match http or https

Tags: html, https

I have seen in a number of place where they used "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/...", they never worked for me. I had to use http with them.

Now I have enabled https on my site and from various questions, the answer appears that if you use "//" it will match either http or https (which ever is in the url) but that does not work for me. It does not match. It always pull https version. As an example, this is in my code

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you got to view-source:https://www.peshawar.co/peshawar/, you will http version being pulled. The same is true for all other links.

So my question is what am I doing wrong? Some relevent questions

[Problems loading style sheets over https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452519/problems-loading-style-sheets-over-https)

[Is it valid to replace http:// with // in a <script src="http://...">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http)

Also ideally I need a solution that works locally as well as on domain.

Answer (score 0):

OK My bad. I was editing the wrong file. // does work :)