# Blazor and CSS on IIS server with Https

Tags: css, iis, https, blazor

I have uploaded my code to an IIS server where we have added https on.
My problem now is that the CSS file is not working as it used before. When I run the application in my local machine it runs perfect. As you can see in the picture [Pix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuvZW.png) ( on the left) the correct why for the style is to separate the sections with ; but in the right side of the picture (on the server) it uses , instead of ;.

This problem started after we implemented the https certificate.

The project that I'm working with is built with Blazor.

What I tried is to figure out if the certificated changed something on the server settings that makes the code to read ; as ,

Comment: maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452519/problems-loading-style-sheets-over-https

Comment: Did not help. like i wrote in my question. It works fine when I run it in my local machine and the https setup in my iis. But as soon as I deploy it in the server the style gets messy like i showed in the picture in my question

Comment: Is this Blazor Server or WASM? How are you referencing the CSS?

Comment: This is a Blazor WASM application. I have not change any of the default reference to the CSS. When I created the project in my lcoal computer I configured it to be able to run in https (you can do that when you create the project). During all the test on my localmachine it is working fine, and iI can see that it is using the style from the css. Do you have any idea on what could be wrong?

Comment: Need a lot more information but have you tried emptying your browser's cache or even using a different browser? Is there any relevant error message in the console?

Comment: Yes, The console doesn't give any errors. I have the picture with warnings uploaded in my question (blue text: Pix). I have tried checked both in edge and chrome, and also tried it in "Incognito mode". Still the same problem. This problem started after we implemented the LSS certificat to use https. Before this the tables where looking fine.

Comment: I solved this buy recreating the publish script. Some how it broke when it created and changed http to https in the json.